# Sending Text One Character at a time fails with "cannot convert from char to string"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send a string one character at a time. When I try the code below it isn't working. It says `Argument 1: cannot convert from char to string`. I know this is probably something simple I am not doing, I just can't think of what it is.

```
    public void SelectUnit(string unitStr)
    {
        // Enter the text for the search
        new LufasWebManager().Stall(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < unitStr.Length; i++)
        {
            unitTxt.SendText(unitStr[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        
        new LufasWebManager().Stall(2000);

        // Locate the correct result
        var unitSearchResult = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//lfs-search-results-drop-list/div/div/div[contains(text(), '{unitStr}')]"));

        // And then click it
        unitSearchResult.Click();
    }
```

It is not working when I try the `unitStr[i]`.

Comment: `It says something about` - please quote the error message exactly. --- Also, creating new throw-away instances of `LufasWebManager` for each method call seems wasteful, but we don't know what it's doing.

Comment: unitTxt.SendText(unitStr[i]); what is the unitTxt element? is it a form? are you trying to send text to the text box?

Comment: unitTxt is a text box I am sending the string to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot convert from char to string

So send a string:

```
unitTxt.SendText(unitStr[i].ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was missing. I feel pretty dumb I couldn't think of that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is because the SendText method is expecting a string

```
public void SelectUnit(string unitStr)
{
   
    new LufasWebManager().Stall(500);
    for (int i = 0; i < unitStr.Length; i++)
    {
        unitTxt.SendText(unitStr[i].ToString()); // Dis is where you convert char to string
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    new LufasWebManager().Stall(2000);

    
    var unitSearchResult = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//lfs-search-results-drop-list/div/div/div[contains(text(), '{unitStr}')]"));

  
    unitSearchResult.Click();
}
```